# Tried to change Xubuntu theme, but font looks weird (gtk3)

Tags: xubuntu, themes, gtk

I tried multiple themes, and installed them using pling store. All of them are supposedly compatible with gtk3, which apparently is the one I have installed

```
$ dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version' | cut -d' ' -f2-
3.22.30-1ubuntu4version
```

Al the themes I tried are compatible with my GTK (Nord theme for example)
https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1267246/

But the theme looks wrong, there are no buttons (minimize, expand...), and the font looks weird:
[image: This is how my desktop looks]

The theme is installed in `~/.themes` and I gave `777` perms to the whole directory.

Tried restarting the PC and it won't work anyway. The Summarizing the only stuff that changed when I changed the theme was that now the console is dark, but nothing else. And now the "title" of the console looks broken too.

What's the issue there? I put the Nord there as an example, but none of them works.

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Xubuntu.  Xubuntu is now fully GTK+3 (library wise) but that is reasonably recent.  It looks like you are using 18.04 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libgtk-3-0) where Xubuntu hadn't completed the move to GTK+3 fully though libraries & themes are not the same thing.

Comment: Your question appears to be raising a complaint rather than seeking an answer.  Could you please clarify what you are seeking?

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat I think it's not so much a complaint as an issue of how things work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your issue.

I downloaded `Nordic.tar.xz` from https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1267246/ and copied the *Nordic* folder over to `~/.themes`.

Now, you need to do **two** things:

- First, open *Appearances* and select *Nordic*. Doing this will make your gtk2 and gtk3 applications use *Nordic* for things like the menu bar, menu dropdowns, child and dialogue windows, and scrollbars.
- But, as you've seen, the appearance of text in your title bar and of other elements in the title bar such as the minimize, maximize, and close buttons will **not** change. They will obey the theme currently being used by XFCE's *xfwm4* window manager. To use *Nordic's* window manager theme (in `~/.config/themes/Nordic/xfwm4`) , open *Window Manager* and again select *Nordic*.

To illustrate, this image shows the *Nordic* theme for the GTK aspect but the *Greybird* theme for the window manager:

[image: Nordic GTK theme and Greybird window manager theme]

This next image uses *Nordic* for both:

[image: Nordic for both GTK and window manager]

---

In short, Xubuntu allows you to use the GTK theme from one theme and the window manager theme from something else. But, for consistency, it maybe appropriate to use all the theme components from one theme.